# How to find output in a collection using max and where condition in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, bson

I am having a table called data here I have data called _id, timeStamp, value. I need to fetch  max value using the where condition for a specific date

`db.data.aggregate([   { "$group": {      "_id": null,   "MaximumValue": { "$max": "$value" }}}]);`

Comment: Can you show your data model and expected output?

Comment: @mickl Please review the below model and consider timestamp was logged as double...that's not an issue...
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e786534018df110a7a2a92f"),
    "timeStamp" : 1584948532188.0,
    "value" :2124
        }
        
        
        {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e786534018df110a7a2a930"),
    "timeStamp" : 1584948532288.0,
    "value" :231
        }
        
        {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e786534018df110a7a2a931"),
    "timeStamp" : 1584948532387.0,
    "value" :4567
        }

Comment: So it seems like you need to use `$match` for timestamp before you run `$group` but I would need to see some sample data to answer. Basically `$match` becomes your "where". Have you tried that?

Comment: @mickl Let me check it once...

Comment: @mickl Thanks mate! Working :)

Comment: Cool, sample data always helps :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213441/discussion-between-arul-and-mickl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$match` before you run `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { timeStamp: 1584948532188.0 } },
    { $group: { _id: null, maxVal: { $max: "$value" } } }
])
```

then `$max` is only applied on filtered set of documents

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RSNty7TAIHR)